# How Can I Get Api Excution Time in Azure Logic App

Tags: api, azure-logic-apps

Is there any way to Get https request duration time in the azure logic app

Comment: Please elaborate on the question   what execution time you want?? End to end of the entire  logic app or just one particular action?? And how do you want to get it??

Comment: I Want To Get Each action duration and I want to store it in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can get the execution time of one action directly in a variable. For a workaround, we can just get the duration time by the solution below:
[image]

The first expression is:

```
int(ticks(utcNow()))
```

And the second expression is:

```
sub(int(ticks(utcNow())),variables('currentTime'))
```

After running it, we can get the duration time(**the unit of time is "ns"**):
[image]

By the way, we can also see the actions' duration time from monitor. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics) (just provided for your reference)
[image]